# Can I use bigchainDB server with django instead of using sqlite?

Tags: django, sqlite, blockchain, distributed-database, bigchaindb

I am creating degree verification process using blockchain approach which contain six main entities. By entities I mean to say consensus mechanism will evolve around these six entities, so for this I need to build a distributed database. Two approaches came into my mind

One approach of achieving this is to completely built everything from scratch: Separate database for each node in sqlite and then connect each node with some type of query.

Another approach is to use bigchainDB server which is a distributed database server based on blockchain.

Now my question which approach is feasible? I don't know whether bigchainDB server is compatible with django or not since they haven't mention anything about it in their docs.

If anyone have use bigchainDB please help me out. I am really confused as to which approach should I follow.